# Supervisor & Docker: How to exit Supervisor if a service doesn't start?

Tags: docker, supervisord

I'm currently using Supervisor inside my Docker images to start and manage my services and I would like to configure Supervisor to exit if at least one of these services entered FATAL state.

Doing that, I want to avoid to have Docker containers in running state when nothing except Supervisor has succeeded to start.

Comment: If this is a real requirement, consider breaking your services into separate containers.    You are asking supervisord to commit suicide.

Comment: I was more seeing this like a "resignation" after he became useless (no work to do) than like a "suicide" :-)

Comment: I don't think supervisord can commit suicide currently, so no matter what you'll need an external process to monitor it. Could do that in the container or outside of it. Probably easiest to run a command from outside the container to check supervisor and if nothing is working, then kill the container. Or maybe make a supervisor program:xxx section that runs a script that checks supervisor and commits suicide? :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a Supervisor [event listener](http://supervisord.org/events.html). Subscribe it to the event `PROCESS_STATE_FATAL`, and respond to the event by sending a SIGTERM to supervisord, which you are presumably running as PID 1 within the container.

Answer (score 9):

As mhsmith mentioned, an event listener is the best way to achieve this. You could use the following listener (`ADD` this as e.g. `/usr/local/bin/exit-event-listener`):

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import signal

from supervisor import childutils

def main():
    while True:
        headers, payload = childutils.listener.wait()
        childutils.listener.ok()
        if headers['eventname'] != 'PROCESS_STATE_FATAL':
            continue
        os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGTERM)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And then, register it with supervisor:

```
[eventlistener:exit_on_any_fatal]
command=exit-event-listener
events=PROCESS_STATE_FATAL
```

Comment: Thanks for describing this approach. However, I was not able to make it work - `exit-event-listener` returned exit code 127 (`Command not found`), so I had to replace `command=exit-event-listener` with `command=python exit-event-listener`.